# What is the term of feature used by on-the-fly checkers?

Tags: neovim, syntax-highlighting, lsp

Here are two screenshots, with vim and neovim, both with configured language server protocol and showing same file:

Neovim:
[image: neovim]

Vim:
[image: vim]

I want to configure neovim to have same style as vim -- I do not like warning message to appear mixed with my code. What is the name of the option?

Comment: Are you using neovim's native LSP client or a plugin?

Comment: This one: Plug 'https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell the term for that feature is *inline diagnostics*. I don't see any obvious source (like neovim help) for an answer to how to disable it but I found these two possible solutions:

```
vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/publishDiagnostics"] = vim.lsp.with(
    vim.lsp.diagnostic.on_publish_diagnostics, {
        virtual_text = false
    }
)
```

Source: [How to disable inline buffer error messages?](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/issues/662)

```
lua << EOF
  local nvim_lsp = require'nvim_lsp'
  -- Disable Diagnostcs globally
  vim.lsp.handlers["textDocument/publishDiagnostics"] = function() end
EOF
```

Source: [[Neovim LSP] How to disable diagnostics?](https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/gtta9p/neovim_lsp_how_to_disable_diagnostics/?sort=old)

*Note: I modified the second answer slightly as the original used a deprecated variable name.*

**Update:** Feedback from OP as follows...

- Second solution also disabled gutter information which is not what they want.
- First solution is not precisely what was hoped for but works well enough. It looks like this: https://asciinema.org/a/oFpPE1LqZFbE6Lqc1W8ShPGL1

The first solution removes the inline diagnostics. You can get diagnostics in a floating window with command `vim.lsp.diagnostic.show_line_diagnostics()`.

The GitHub page for [LSP client configuration](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig) shows this mapping for that command:

```
buf_set_keymap('n', '<space>e', '<cmd>lua vim.lsp.diagnostic.show_line_diagnostics()<CR>', opts)
```

Finally, apparently the first solution above can also be found here: `:help lsp-handler`.

Comment: Second one does not work for me -- there is no such thing as vim.lsp.callbacks. And if I replace it with vim.lsp.handlers, mark in left columns disappears fully.

Comment: First approach works -- inline text disappears, mark on the left stays. I get see message in pop-up menu via `vim.lsp.diagnostic.show_line_diagnostics()`. Not exactly the same as in vim, but good enough for my needs.

Comment: Now it looks like this: https://asciinema.org/a/oFpPE1LqZFbE6Lqc1W8ShPGL1

Comment: You may want to add it into your answer for future readers. I mapped "<space>e" as instructed here: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig

Comment: First answer could be found starting from ":help lsp-handler".

Comment: I forget the words neovim uses, but something like float or virtual text

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Inline diagnostics are virtual text. Floats or floating windows are like Vim popups...that's where OP's diagnostics now show up.